# spring boot security oauth2 token intospect to oauth2 server from spring as backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

i am new to oauth2.0 and trying to introspect token which is send in request headers from angular to spring endpoint. i want to configure web security as to how it can access the endpoint in authorization server for token validation for each incoming request to spring back end.

angular 2 -- > get token from authorization server.

angular 2 -> https request sends token in headers to --> spring boot backend

**spring backend (spring-boot) - > to configure security for each incoming request to introspect token. and then send the response back to angular 2**

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question ?